# Question on positive semidefinite ordering of matrices.

Tags: matrices

We have symmetric, positive definite matrices $ {\bf A}, {\bf B},{\bf C}, {\bf D} \in {\bf R}^{n\times n}$ with 
$$\bf A \leq \bf B$$
and 
$$\bf C \leq \bf D$$
which means that the differences $(\bf B - \bf A)$ and $(\bf D - \bf C)$ are positive semidefinite.
From this, it follows
$$\bf CAC^T \leq \bf CBC^T$$
and
$${\bf DAD^T} \leq {\bf DBD^T} \ .$$

My question is: Does also
$$\bf CAC^T \leq \bf DBD^T$$
hold? How can I prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: Ultimately, it would seem that you need to determine whether
$$
CAC^T \leq DAD^T
$$

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right. So, the question is whether $${\bf C A C^T} \leq {\bf D A D^T}$$ holds in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define: 
$$
A = B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\quad
C = I,\quad D = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}
$$
We calculate:
$$
DBD^T = \pmatrix{2&0\\1&0}D = \pmatrix{4&2\\2&1}
$$
Note that $DBD^T - CAC^T$ is **not** positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

If your conjecture holds, then in the special case where $A=B=I$, we would have $C^2\le D^2$ whenever $0<C\le D$. However, it is well known that the square function is not matrix monotone. Therefore your conjecture is false in general.